# I'm trying to attach this php code to html file and cant figure out

Tags: authentication

php require('includes/config.php');

if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }

$title = 'main';

require('layout/header.php');

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link href=
'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700|Open+Sans:400,300,700'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- CSS reset -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- Resource style -->

<script src="js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript">
```

```
<title>
  main menuw
</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP code should be between the '<?php' and '?>'

Your server should support PHP